# How to merge multiple csv files into a single parquet file in azure data flow?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I would like to merge multiple CSV files in AzureDataFlow and output them to a single Parquet file, but I am having trouble with the data source file.

There are two types of data source files.
One has a header and the other does not.
These files have the same column names and I would like to merge them, but I don't know how.
I want to merge the files with headers by aligning the headers to the files with headers.

**In other words,I want to combine files with headers with files without headers.**

I have already tried one method.
That is to skip the first line of a file that has a header, merge it with the header removed, and then add the header in the mapping.
However, that method requires me to manually change the mapping every time the header of the data source is changed.
This is not a smart approach.
Any answers would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to combine the 2 files, use Union with the By Position method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-union.

If the columns do not line-up positionally, you can rearrange the column ordering with a Select transformation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I'll try it tomorrow, but I have a question.
Do I use wildcard in source dataset?
I want to combine 2~4000 files into a single file.
I'm looking for your answer. Thank you.